# Is it possible to suppress initramfs logs during shutdown?

Tags: linux-kernel, initramfs, initrd, ramdisk

There are quite a few Linux kernel parameters that can prevent the boot and shutdown logs from appearing on the screen.

I was able to set the following kernel parameters to achieve a completely silent boot:

```
quiet systemd.show_status=0 loglevel=3 udev.log_level=3 vt.global_cursor_default=0
```

However, the shutdown screen still shows some messages despite the kernel parameters being set.

These messages show up strictly at the `initramfs` stage of shutdown.

For example, I sometimes get the following messages:

```
sd-umoun[367339]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
sd-umoun[367348]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev: Device or resource busy
shutdown[1]: Could not detach DM /dev/dm-1: Device or resource busy
shutdown[1]: Could not detach DM /dev/dm-0: Device or resource busy
shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize file systems, DM devices, ignoring.
```

These are due to some configuration problems with the `plymouth` service and are mostly harmless.

Despite the cause of the messages, I would like to know if it's possible to hide **all** logs produced at this stage of the shutdown process?

Is there a way to tell the initrd system to not print any logs to the console during shutdown, even if they are errors?

I tried to prepend `rd.` to some of the kernel parameters, but from what I understand these are redundant with the normal kernel parameters i.e. `rd.loglevel=0` doesn't do anything extra in regards to the ramdisk image.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to supress the logs with another kernel parameter:

```
systemd.log_level=2
```

Where `2` is `crit` level of logging.

Given that the messages above are errors, setting `systemd.log_level=3` makes them appear again.